# How to fetch players kill count in Pubg Mobile of custom match?

Tags: java, python, android, api, pubg

I am trying to make a program where I can populate all the players of my custom match in **Pubg Mobile**, with their kills count in the end of the match.
Basically somewhat like a list of all the players in that custom match with their number of kills.
[please see this image how the final list has been prepared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9u2d.png)

I don't know how they are doing but , that must not be any manual action.

Please any guidance or help is highly appreciated!

Comment: did you tried anything

Comment: Still not anything but looking forward dive into pubg official API

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a Pubg Mobile Official API to get the results of a match. So, it is not possible for now.

Comment: Is there ANY other method to retrieve PUBG Mobile player data?